# How to extract every odd numbered element in list

Tags: r, list

I want to extract every odd (or even) numbered element in list.

```
#example data
ls <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), c(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), c(16,17,18,19,20,21))

ls
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

[[3]]
[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

In this example I want to be able to extract only the first and third element in the list. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: another alternative.. `ls[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`. reverse the logicals to extract evens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should solve your problem:

```
my_list[seq(1, length(my_list), 2)]
```

i would advise you against using inbuilt R functions as names for your objects (`ls`). also look up some elementary R list manipulations, indexing, etc